# Http client laravel

Tags: php, laravel

After the data is retrieved, the data is converted to an array type, no longer an object like when testing in the service, this affects a number of problems, causing me to convert it back to an object. I want to ask how to get data about object type. Thanks.

```
        $ordersPaginate = Http::get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders?limit=$limit&column=$column&sort=$sort");
        $ordersPaginate = json_decode($ordersPaginate, false);  //-> array
                    
        //convert the received array to an order object
        $arr = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($ordersPaginate as $key => $paginate)
        {
            $order = new Order(['id' => $paginate -> id,
                                'user_id' => $paginate -> user_id,
                                'shipping_fee' => $paginate -> shipping_fee,
                                'total' => $paginate -> total,
                                'payment' => $paginate -> payment,
                                'status_id' => $paginate -> status_id,
                                'created_at' => $paginate -> created_at,
                                'updated_at' => $paginate -> updated_at,
        
            ]);
            $arr[$i] = $order;
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
        dd($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Http client has a method called `object()` to return object

```
$ordersPaginate = Http::get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders?limit=$limit&column=$column&sort=$sort");


if($ordersPaginate->successful()){
 
   foreach($ordersPaginate->object() as $key => $paginate){
    
   }
}
```

Comment: error: Call to a member function successful() on array

Comment: @PhạmTiếnLong remove this line   $ordersPaginate = json_decode($ordersPaginate, false); no need of this line .

Comment: it's still an array

Comment: @PhạmTiếnLong can you show updated code here in comment .full code